# recursion and the Windows attrib command

Tags: windows, globbing

A link to a reference... [Microsoft on the Windows attrib command.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attrib)

The description of the `/d` option... "Applies attrib and any command-line options to directories."

`attrib` used without a path prints attributes for files only in the current directory. When `attrib` is used without a path the `/d` option seems to mean "do it for directories in addition to files" and that is not the understanding I would receive from the description of `/d` so I'm not sure if the description is lacking or if somehow this is supposed to be obvious. I know files and directories are distinct in Windows (but in Linux directories are a subclass of the class of files).

From testing with the read-only attribute `+r` / `-r` are some of my observations...

```
attrib    prints attributes for files in the current directory
attrib /d   prints attributes for files and directories in the current directory
attrib +r /s /d dir    sets the attributes for the directory not recursively
attrib +r /s /d dir\*   sets the attributes for files and directories recursively
attrib +r /s /d * sets attribs for files and dirs in current dir and recursively
```

The description of the `/s` option... "Applies attrib and any command-line options to matching files in the current directory and all of its subdirectories." Since recursion is not mentioned perhaps the expectation should have been that the 3rd, 4th, and 5th commands should not have recursed, but in testing we can demonstrate that recursion is possible. There is a documentation problem... operating on "all of its subdirectories" is not the same as recursion which is understood to mean **all levels** of subdirectories.

Why is the third example not already recursive?  To my eye the 3rd example is a subset of the 5th example.

**Addendum** for the commenter that said directories cannot be read-only...
[image: picture]

Comment: Read-only does not apply to folders, as folders have no content that can be read. It's perhaps not the best example. Hidden might be better (ensure you can see hidden files/folders before trying).

Comment: @harrymc Read-only does apply to folders. Try it. The content of a directory or folder is the data that records what files are metaphorically inside the folder. The read-only setting of a folder prevents files from being deleted or added.

Comment: @H2ONaCl No it doesn't. Try it.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Check out the addendum. I show a file and a directory after applying `-r` and after applying `+r`.

Comment: The addendum only shows that the attribute has been set; it doesn't show that the attribute has any actual effect of preventing files from being created or deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attrib` handles the path argument in a somewhat unconventional way. Unlike most modern tools, it does not simply use the given path as the root from which to start recursing – instead it splits the path into two parts (directory and base name), then the 'directory' part becomes the starting point for the recursive search while the 'base name' is used as a *filter* for search results.

So while the 3rd example (`attrib /s /d dir`) *is* recursive, it **does not mean** "recursively search the directory `dir` for all objects" (like most would expect) – rather, it means "recursively search the current directory for objects named `dir`". The recursive search finds exactly one result (`.\dir`).

On the other hand, `attrib /s /d foo\*` is handled like `dir="foo", match="*"` so it starts the search from `foo` in the current directory and looks for any subdirectories matching the name `*`.

The `dir` built-in command in Cmd.exe operates in the same way. For example, if you do `dir /s foo`; it may output `one\two\three\foo`.

Comment: The point was regarding _how_ the recursion is implemented inside the program – `attrib /s foo` does not start recursing from `.\foo`.

Comment: In other words `attrib /s foo` is recursive and there is a requirement to match `foo`.  The is like my 3rd example.